# how to change the state of a text with hover in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the state of A text by on mouse over on an image but the function is not working.

I have set the state of the heading and parah in tye function but it would not working.

export default class portfolio extends Component {

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={

        heading:"helo world",
        parah:""

    }

    this.handleDiscription = this.handleDiscription.bind(this);
}

handleDiscription=()=>{
    this.setState={
        heading:"Reading Friends",
        parah:"what do you mean"
    }
}


render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <div>

                    <div  className="row ">
                    <div className="row ">
                        <div  className="reading-friends" style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                            <h1 className="heading" style={{fontSize:'50px',fontWeight:'bold',marginTop:'140px',marginBottom:'200px',fontFamily:"catamaran,sans-serif"}} OnClick={this.handleDiscription}>{this.state.heading}</h1>
                            <p className="parah">{this.state.parah}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <div style={{textAlign:'center'}} className="opti-care">
                        <h1  style={{fontSize:'50px',fontWeight:'bold',marginBottom:'200px',fontFamily:"catamaran,sans-serif"}}>Opticare Solution</h1>
                        <p>OptiCare Solution is a complete mini ERP for opticians and optometrists.<br/>
                             We are the first to bring such an extensive solution in the field of Optometry,<br></br>
                              providing features that are robust and easy to use.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row"></div>
                </div>
                <div style={{marginTop:'270px'}} className="row ">

                <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
             <Reading
             show={this.handleDiscription}

             />
```

//child component

Comment: You are using setState incorrectly, it’s a function that takes arguments. Currently you are reassigning the value of the setState function, not passing something to it to update state. Please review the documentation first https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: can you please edit the code?

Comment: I shall be very thankfull to you.

Comment: You want to move the `handleDescription` method to an `onMouseOver` and then reset the state with a `onMouseOut`. And on either the img element itself or it’s div container. In addition to following the advice in the first answer. Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is how you are using [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). You are currently attempting to reassign the value of `setState()` instead of passing an argument to it of the new state you want set:

```
handleDiscription = () => {
    this.setState({
        heading:"Reading Friends",
        parah:"what do you mean"
    });
}
```

The next issue is you are attempting to bind to `OnClick` instead of `onClick` or `onHover`. It should be at minimum `onClick` with a lowercase "o":

```
onClick={this.handleDiscription}
```

That being said, you mention "hover" in the title, but you are targeting click events, did you instead mean:

```
onMouseEnter={this.handleDiscription}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: how can i pass this method to a child component

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. That would be a different question, but basically three steps: 1) Update handleDiscription to take an argument of the payload/state (if needed) 2) Pass the function as a prop to the child `<SomeChildComponent handleDiscription={this.handleDiscription} />` 3) In the child, call the function from props `this.props. handleDiscription(somePayload)`

Comment: can we change the state of image by set state?

Comment: If you mean change the value of src property of an <img> via state and setState, then yes you can.

Comment: @MuhammadZain Update your question with the updated code you have so far including the child component, the updates to the hover/mouseOver handler and what have tried so far.

Comment: Ok I will try it first myself If I don't then I will post the question.